# Wifi slow to find correct network

Tags: wi-fi

I have a a10 tab 2 lenovo. I recently reflashed the original new rom. Before everything was working except the wifi was slow(lots of lag) which was on a hacked rom for some similar tab.

The problem I have now is that when I turn on the device for the first time, the main wifi network is not found nor loaded. It either takes a few minutes or I have to simply open the wifi settings in which it then finds and connects to it. It ends up connecting to a more remote network which is too slow to use.

My phone is connected to the same networks and it finds and uses the correct network immediately without issue as did the tablet before I changed roms.

I'm not sure if the tablet thinks that the first network it connects to is better(sometimes I use it, but rarely, only when I'm take it to the other side of the house) or what. It seems it is the tablet. I'd basically want it to *always* use the main network A(which is 100% signal strength) rather than the 50% strength of network B that it connects to(which is on the other side of the house).

any ideas why this is doing that and how to change it? Basically I want it to connect to network A. I suppose I could forget network B and it might do it but then I'd have to remember the wifi pass to it and enter it in every time and have it forget every time... just to fix a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

I'm pretty sure it must be a setting/configuration on the tab since it was working before the rom change and my phone works fine which has identical wifi setup, locations, etc.

It is android 6 rooted.

[The problem is that when I turn on the device, go to a browser I get wifi error. I open the wifi settings, it connects without me telling it which network. I have to clear the browser so it stops using the old wifi network, then everything works]

Comment: Try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roamingsoft.manager) - you can specify the connection order

Comment: @beeshyams I'd rather not install an app. Surely there is some config file that can be modified or settings that do not require some app to run constantly for a temporary thing.

Comment: I understand. That rules out automation option to disconnect on connection to the undesired WiFi. See if enabling `Always allow WiFi Roam scans` in developer options helps- a guess

Comment: If it is happening only on this ROM, there may be a fix discussed in ROM forums

Comment: Some ROMs offer "priority settings" – so the other, slower WiFi might be setup with a higher priority, thus taking precendence over the stronger, closer one. Try removing that slower one from your "known WiFi networks" list and see if that helps.

Comment: @Izzy: suppose it did, as I said, it would not be acceptable as a solution because I need both active. I can't be having to mess with wi-fi configurations ever time I use the device or move to the other side of the house. So, if was the problem, what would be the permanent solution?

Comment: @beeshyams I will try that option. I could install the app but I imagine it requires continual running to fix. Surely if an app can do it then it is a settings/configuration issue. It would be nice if someone new where the settings are at and which ones would be the problem and I could mess with them.

Comment: I of course already thought so – but didn't want to go into depths before establishing if it's worth it. If the above works out (i.e. without the 2nd network, the device connects to the "main network" as planned), I'd re-add the other one and see if the issue returns (hopefully it does not). If it returns, we'd know a triffle better in which direction to investigate further. As your device is rooted, that would be e.g. taking a look at the `wpa_supplicant.conf` and checking the `priority=` parameters of the two networks.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, I'll try to figure it out from here. I should mention though, that the network is not listed in the list of networks at the start. It lists every other one but for some reason the main one is not and takes a minute to show or so. So, I would imagine if it were strictly a priority issue that it would still show the network, it just wouldn't connect? It seems like the device doesn't even try to find the network until I go in to the wifi settings and then it decides to look for it.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's different. Anything specific to that network, like e.g. a hidden BSSID? That would explain why it shows up delayed. And its showing up delayed is most likely the reason why the other one connects first and, once connected, the "real one" is ignored. Some [tag:automation] app could possibly work-around that (along the lines of "if %WIFI in reach and not connected, connect that regardless whether you're already connect to something else").

Comment: @Izzy yeah, I think it's hidden. But my phone connects immediately and has the exact same setup(same location, etc). I think it was fine before the rom change. I thought it might be because it was hidden but since it works fine on my android phone(android 4 though) I thought it might be something else. I'll unhide it and see. Strange that it would matter since it knows the name.

Comment: @Izzy so, I wasn't able to get it to work. I looked at a wifi analyzer and noticed that there is another network that is on the same channel, says it uses the same router model, and when the wifi eventually connects correctly(at first doesn't work) it goes from channel 6 to channel 6(8). So I'm wondering if there is some type of interference? maybe my phone as a weaker antenna and so the other network is out of range(it's across the street)? This wouldn't explain the past but maybe the rom tweaked the strength of the reception and now it's getting interference or they changed something.

Comment: Also, the other wifi in my house is on the same channel. I'll try to change the channel when I get a chance and maybe that will solve it. It doesn't seem like it should be the problem since the main one is about -40dB while the other is -72dB(11 times less powerful).

Comment: "says it uses the same router model": most routers have their models set as BSSID by default. If that's the case with the two, it could indeed be a bit confusing (though it shouldn't as the MAC addresses should differ) – so next to the channel, I'd think about using a "more unique" BSSID as well. Cannot hurt :)

Comment: @Izzy Ok, I made the SSID non-hidden and it now connects like it's suppose to. I noticed that the channel was 11instead of 6 so that might had something to do with it, but it was automatic. This router runs in bridged mode and I'm not sure if it uses the same ch as the main router, but it always looks to use it. This might be the problem though since the other router might think ch 6 is good where it is at but it's not good where the bridged one is. In any case, it still has to be an issue with the device ultimately because my phone has no issues either way.